# Using a .NET DLL in JAVA SCRIPT - Registered through REGASM

Tags: javascript, c#, regasm

I have registered a .NET DLL using REGASM and registration is successful. I'm able to create object of the classes and use them in my Javascript. The class I consume i sa non static one.

This is how I'm using and it is working,

```
var objDP = new ActiveXObject("PE.Core.PacketExtractor"); 
objDP.PrintMessage();
objDP.Start();
```

My problem :

I have a methods in my C# class which I would like to call and get the value. The method signature is given below,

Signature : `Get_Current_Faults(ref PEFaults my_faults);`

Usage : `Get_Current_Faults(my_faults);`

In this method the "PEFaults" is a public C# Struct. This is also COM Visible and registered as I could see an entry in the Registry.

I tried to get data in JavaScript by doing the following,

```
var objFault = new ActiveXObject("PE.Core.PE_FAULTS"); 
objDP.Get_Current_Faults(ref objFault);

WScript.echo(objFault.Temperature);
```

But this is not working and giving an error "Automation Server cant create an object" @ PE.Core.CURRENT_FAULTS object creation.

Cant we create an object of Struct in JS ? Any idea how to handle a ref parameter ? How else I can make this work ?

Please advise me. Thanks.

Comment: Javascript has no notion of structs, only objects. Could it be that your struct should in fact be a class?

Comment: @loannis : Thanks for your response. I agree JS would not know Struct. In C# this is a structure. I'm trying to create an obj out of it in JS using the same syntax that I have used to create an obj out of my class ( first code snippet). How would it matter for JavaScript ? Any idea. I would not be able to convert this Struct in to a class due other reasons.

Comment: It might matter because a struct is not equivalent to a class, being an immutable construct, and so the windows scripting host might not know how to provide its equivalent class. I'm just guessing here, however.